# issue with slider

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having some issue with the position of a slider. It goes outside his holder, somewhere in the right. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in the CSS but can't remember what exactly.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="carousel">
      <img src="css/images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="css/images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="css/images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="pagination">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider { position: relative; width: 100%; }
.carousel img { width: 781px; display: block; }

.pagination { position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
.pagination a { background: url(images/pagination.png) no-repeat 0 bottom; height: 12px; width: 12px; float: left; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; padding: 0 3px 0 0; }
.pagination a:hover,
.pagination a.selected { background-position: 0 0; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $(".carousel").carouFredSel({
        items: 1,
        scroll: {
            fx: "fade"
        },
        auto: 4000,
        width:781,
        pagination: ".pagination"
    });

});
```

I've found the mistake I was missing `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

nice job in finding the mistake. Yes overflow is easily overlooked.